# Child entity not getting persisted when saving parent entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have two entities with one-to-one relationships.

They are as follows,

```
@Entity
class Parent {

@Id
private String id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Child child;

// getter setter

}

@Entity
public class Child {

@Id
private String id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Parent parent;

// getter setter

}



@Service
public TestService {

@Autowired
private ParentRepository parentRepository;

public void testMethod() {

// Creating new ChildElement
Parent p = parentRepository.findById("ID1").get();
Child c = parent.getChild()
if(c == null) {
c = new Child() 
c.setId("ID2");
}
// set child with some property

p.setChild(c);

parentRepository.save(p);

}

}
```

This code is working when I am creating a new child entity for the first time. But when updating the child entity, it is not getting updated.

Could you please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is related to this line.

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Parent parent;
```

I mean `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`.
When updatable and insertable are equal false it won't be updated I think.

Comment: I can understand your point but in that case insertion should not happen as well, right?

Comment: `insertable=false` means that **JPA** won't include the column in the insert statement when saving the entity. But it will when updating the entity, and it will load it from the database. So try to remove that and see the result.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do bidirectional setting.
Add below line after p.setChild(c).

```
C.setParent(p)
```